# Binding click event for object element which contains video

Tags: javascript

I'm attaching an object element. How to trigger a function when play or pause button is clicked in IE?

```
<object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="test.wmv" width="340" height="280"  id="movie1">
  <param name="src" value="test.wmv" />
  <param name="controller" value="false" />
  <param name="autostart" value="true" />
</object>
```

My js code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("movie1").addEventListener("click", onMovieStateChange, false);
});

function onMovieStateChange() {
    var state = document.movie1.PlayState
    if (state == 0) {
        alert('video ended');
    }
    if (state == 1) {
        alert('video paused');
    }
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use HTML5 video tag? That one has native events for "onplay" and "onpause".

Comment: shouldn't this "var state = document.movie1.PlayState" be "document.getElementById("movie1")"

Comment: @JonasGrumann . Even the click event not triggering.
    <div id="movieHolder">
    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="test.wmv" width="340" height="280" id="movie1">
      <param name="src" value="test.wmv" />
      <param name="controller" value="false" />
      <param name="autostart" value="true" />
    </object>
    </div>

Comment: I tried to put outer div and click event for that but that itself taking precedence in html.

Comment: I think the click event will not be delegated to the DOM with an object-tag video.